# CSS Margins not working with block-elements

Tags: css, html, margin

It seems that margins are not being respected by my block-level elements.
I'm unable to solve this issue without converting the block-level elements to inline-block - which I don't want to do - why would I? They should be block :P

Code @ Plunker:
http://embed.plnkr.co/oRMieH

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: a) ALWAYS post your code in your question and 2) which specific margins are you referring to?

Comment: provide a fiddle, so someone could help you

Comment: there is a link to the a plnkr for the code.  and I'm referring to margin-top/bottom

Comment: Which margin-top margin-bottom? Read your question - and then write it again.

Comment: looks like you're searching for some free online debugger? Your blog site may contain misc contents, refer to many resources, the html code may be too long to scan (need much time), ... even it may not be well designed. I think many don't even want to get started to help you debug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the vertical margins are collapsing. You can read about it, or you can just put double margin-bottom on the top element and forget the margin-top. I only use margin-bottom because when building small screen first, the need for margin-top is very rare for me.

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/margin/

Comment: can't believe I forgot about collapsing margins!  Thanks for the reminder.  I also agree with your statement about using margin-bottom for a small-screen first approach.  Make complete sense.

Answer (score -1):

It has to do with position: absolute; It creates it's own layer and can't work with margins. You could try position: relative;